# array create issue with german language

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, character-encoding

I have database in german language. I am fetching data from database and create array. problem is some german characters are converted special character. thats why not able to encode array in json. i have also tried by putting header for german language but it is for display purpose so it is not works.

please check below array created

[image]

if i copy and paste that same string manually and create array than it create perfect array. can you please solve issue.

[image]

after use of

htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);

[image]

you can see have display both string one is fetched from database and one is encoded using htmlentities. you can see last index of array is empty so htmlentities could not encode it.

Comment: what database you have? (mysql, postgre, mssql, bigdata,mongodb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape your string. Try this:

```
// $str, encode quotes, UTF-8 encoding, false (do not double encode).
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);
```

Replace $str with your string. This should fix your issue.

Comment: please see my result in question i have edit after use of htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', false);

Comment: Is all of your character encoding in check? Like, is your document set to UTF-8 and is your database storing data in utf8_unicode_ci too?

Comment: you are right but it is german language thats why required different encoding standard  echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1', false);  thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question mark in a black diamond is often caused by

- latin1 encoding of text in the client, and
- `SET NAMES latin1` or otherwise picking (or defaulting to) latin1 when connecting, and
- (It does not matter what `CHARACTER SET` the table/columns is.), and
- Saying `<meta charset=UTF-8>` in the html.

A simple fix is to change the last step to be `<meta charset=ISO-8859-1>`, thereby working only with latin1, not utf8.  That's "ok" for Western Europe, but won't work for Asia.

The "right" fix is to go with utf8mb4 at all for steps.